# Newey-West standard errors with Mean Groups/Fama-MacBeth estimator

Tags: r, regression, standard-error

I'm trying to get Newey-West standard errors to work with the output of `pmg()` (Mean Groups/Fama-MacBeth estimator) from the `plm` package.

Following the example from [here](https://landroni.wordpress.com/2012/06/02/fama-macbeth-and-cluster-robust-by-firm-and-time-standard-errors-in-r/):

```
require(foreign)
require(plm)
require(lmtest)
test <- read.dta("http://www.kellogg.northwestern.edu/faculty/petersen/htm/papers/se/test_data.dta")

fpmg <- pmg(y~x, test, index=c("firmid", "year")) # Time index in second position, unlike the example
```

I can use `coeftest` directly just fine to get the Fama-MacBeth standard errors:

```
# Regular “Fama-MacBeth” standard errors
coeftest(fpmg)

# t test of coefficients:
#   
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept) 0.032470   0.071671   0.453   0.6505    
# x           0.969212   0.034782  27.866   <2e-16 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

However, trying to use the Newey-West estimators fails:

```
# Newey-West standard-errors
coeftest(fpmg, vcov = NeweyWest(fpmg, lag=3))

# Error in UseMethod("estfun") : 
#   no applicable method for 'estfun' applied to an object of class "c('pmg', 'panelmodel')"
```

This seems like a shortcoming in the `plm` package. Do you know a way to make this work? Should I code my own `estfun` for `pmg` objects? Code a Newey-West estimator from scratch? Or should I bypass the `plm` package altogether?

Comment: I don't think that `plm` has incorporated a Newey-West estimator yet, at least I do not find anything in the manual. The `NeweyWest`-function is from the `sandwich`-package, which does not deal with panel data, therefore your error. 
You may want to have a look at this thread: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Newey-West-HAC-errors-for-panels-td3231338.html
But I am not aware of any other panel data package.

Comment: Following the thread above, you would to something like this (notice, plm instead of pmg)
`fpmg <- plm(y~x, test, index = c("firmid", "year")); coeftest(fpmg, vcov = function(x) vcovSCC(x, type = "HC1", maxlag = 4))`

Comment: @David That's good information, thanks, I wasn't aware of Driscoll and Kraay (1998) being related to Newey-West, I need to read up on it. However `plm` (vs `pmg`) would not give me a Fama-MacBeth/Means group estimator for the coefficients, I'm afraid.

Comment: tbh. I am not really sure that `pmg` and `plm` will produce similar results. Neither am I sure that D&K produce something similar to N&W... I guess reading up will help :) But please make sure that you share the result! :D

Comment: @David You can replace `pmg` by `plm` in my example above and see, unfortunately the coefficients are different. I'm reading up on D&K and will report my findings. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that we can replace `pmg` and `plm`, I get an error in the `coeftest`, that there is `no applicable method for 'vcovSCC' applied to an object of class "c('pmg', 'panelmodel')"`

Comment: @David My point was this: if you do `plm(y~x, test, index=c("firmid", "year"))` instead of `pmg(y~x, test, index=c("firmid", "year"))`, you'll see that coefficients are different. But yes `vcovSCC` only works on `plm` objects.

Comment: Hello there, any new update on this? Is there a way to avoid the manual (but great) solution below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this is impossible with `plm` package.

However, you could just create them yourself.

Suppose you have:

```
fpmg <- pmg(y~x, test, index = c('year', 'firmid'))
fpmg.coefficients <- fpmg$coefficients
# (Intercept)            x 
#  0.03127797   1.03558610 

coeftest(fpmg)
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept) 0.031278   0.023356  1.3392   0.1806    
# x           1.035586   0.033342 31.0599   <2e-16 ***
```

Then you can simply create the estimators yourself like in:

```
the.years <- unique(test$year)
a.formula <- y ~ x


first.step <-  lapply(the.years, function(a.year) {
                temp.data <- test[test$year == a.year, ]
                an.lm <- lm(a.formula, data = temp.data)
                the.coefficients <- an.lm$coef
                the.results <- as.data.frame(cbind(a.year, t(the.coefficients)))
                the.results
                }) 

first.step.df <- do.call('rbind', first.step)

second.step.coefficients <- apply(first.step.df[, -1], 2, mean)
second.step.coefficients
# (Intercept)           x 
#  0.03127797  1.03558610 

identical(fpmg.coefficients, second.step.coefficients)
# [1] TRUE
```

Check that they are identical both ways just in case.
Last, you can obtain the Newey-West (1987) with one lag adjusted t-statistics for the means with:

```
library(sandwich)
second.step.NW.sigma.sq <- apply(first.step.df[, -1], 2, 
                             function(x) sqrt(NeweyWest(lm(x ~ 1), 
                               lag = 1, prewhite = FALSE)['(Intercept)',       
                                 '(Intercept)']))
second.step.NW.sigma.sq
#  (Intercept)            x 
#   0.02438398   0.02859447
t.statistics.NW.lag.1 <- second.step.coefficients / second.step.NW.sigma.sq

t.statistics.NW.lag.1
# (Intercept)           x 
#    1.282726   36.216301
```

#### Update

In my answer, I had only included the "manual" calculation of the t-statistic, because it is computationally faster.
A more generic solution is to calculcate the Newey-West corrected t-statistics and their p-values with the `coeftest()` function of the `lmtest` package.

```
coeftest(lm(first.step.df$'(Intercept)' ~ 1), vcov = NeweyWest(lm(first.step.df$'(Intercept)' ~ 1), lag = 1, prewhite = FALSE))
# t test of coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept) 0.031278   0.024384  1.2827   0.2316
coeftest(lm(first.step.df$x ~ 1), vcov = NeweyWest(lm(first.step.df$x ~ 1), lag = 1, prewhite = FALSE))
# t test of coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept) 1.035586   0.028594  36.216 4.619e-11 ***
```

Comment: Hi @pidosaurus, great solution indeed. Do you know if a canned solution is available yet?

Comment: I haven't seen any canned as in 'released R package'  solution so far, but I do not meticulously follow CRAN.

Comment: @pidosaurus: Comment and Question. Comment: One can go directly to ` second.step.NW.sigma.sq <- apply(t(fpmg$indcoef), 2, function(x) sqrt(NeweyWest(lm(x ~ 1))['(Intercept)', '(Intercept)']))` after computing `fpmg`. I am not sure what `['(Intercept)', '(Intercept)']` is supposed to do. Seems not to make any difference. Question: to get the p-values, can one do: `second.step.NW.sigma.sq <- apply(t(fpmg$indcoef), 2, function(x) (NeweyWest(lm(x ~ 1))['(Intercept)', '(Intercept)']));
coeftest(fpmg, vcov=diag(second.step.NW.sigma.sq))`

Comment: @BarbaraBukhvalova On your question: No. The diagonal terms of the the `vcov` are variances and you include their square roots. The proper way to do this is: `coeftest(lm(first.step.df$'(Intercept)' ~ 1), vcov=NeweyWest(lm(first.step.df$'(Intercept)' ~ 1), lag = 1, prewhite = FALSE)))` for the intercept and `coeftest(lm(first.step.df$x ~ 1), vcov=NeweyWest(lm(first.step.df$x ~ 1), lag = 1, prewhite = FALSE))` for the regressor. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @BarbaraBukhvalova On your comment: You are right, `['(Intercept)', '(Intercept)']` is reduntant, since the model formula is `x ~ 1`. I included it for verbosity reasons and avoid confusion.
Please do not forget to set `lag = 1, prewhite = FALSE`, since currently the default is `NULL` and `TRUE`, respectively. Setting `prewhite = FALSE` is necessary for the original application of NeweyWest. Setting a rational number of lags depends on your data.
More information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23420454/newey-west-standard-errors-for-ols-in-python

Comment: @pidosaurus Sorry in my code I did delete sqrt so I was using variances. I did NeweyWest without parameters, as according to `sandwich` it is consistent with NW (1994). If that is wrong, I would like to know. What I am still struggling with is the appropriate df's. Do you suggest keeping `floor(bwNeweyWest(model))` and then doing "number of regressions averaged"-1-"the lags from above"? `lm(first.step.df$x ~ 1)$df.residual` is 9 and that does not take the fitted lags into account.

Comment: Hmm: I see `lm(first.step.df$x ~ 1)` is actually 0 for this regression

Comment: I mean `floor(bwNeweyWest(lm(first.step.df$x ~ 1)))` is 0, of course

Comment: Hello @BarbaraBukhvalova . 
Ideally, people should replicate the code of the `NeweyWest()` function and compare it to the original articles (Newey and West 1987 & 1994). I did not have enough time and was not really necessary for my needs so I have not done this replication. Hence, I rely to their documentation in good faith.
In their documentation (p. 14 of https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sandwich/sandwich.pdf), I see that Newey and West (1987) do not require prewhitening, while for (1994) they do. In my case, the statistical significance was not altered with/without prewhitening.

Comment: With respect to the lag length I could follow Newey and West (1987) and set it as $floor[T^{1/4}]$ or (1994) and follow `bwNeweyWest()`. If I were you, I would be alarmed if the choice of lags (nearby numbers) alters the inference. I know that if 4-5 lags is required, u can get a very well different and erroneous inference if you chose to use say 20. My rule of thumb is to follow the literature standards and also do one+ extra mile(s). In my particular case, in finance, I make sure that a reasonable choice of lags or prewhitening does not alter the inference.

Comment: @pidosaurus, my concern is about the appropriate choice of degrees of freedom, not the number of lags. `pmg` function uses n*T-k (in this case 4998). I would have thought it was 9 (10-1), if we do not do lag correction, i.e. number of regressions minus 1 or minus "1+the number of lags".

Comment: @BarbaraBukhvalova Hello and sorry I misread your comment. Oh, this is a very valid concern for which I cannot answer. coeftest() uses the lm object degrees of freedom, but this can have theoretical implications and seems an open issue for future research.. Please let me know if you find something about the appropriate df. More on http://davegiles.blogspot.nl/2012/06/f-tests-based-on-hc-or-hac-covariance.html?m=1 https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v011i10/v11i10.pdf https://www.princeton.edu/~umueller/HACtest.pdf https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sandwich/vignettes/sandwich.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use `tidyverse` to do Newey–West adjustment, since base R methods are too verbose. 3 or 4 years ago, `tidyverse` was immature, but today we can relatively perfect use `tidyverse`. Here is the `tidyverse` method. Besides, `broom` package is used in my answer.

```
# test data:
set.seed(1234)
a <- tibble(
            year = rep(1:20, each = 100),
            firmid = rep(1:100, times = 20),
            x1 = rnorm(2000),
            x2 = rnorm(2000),
            y = 2 + 3 * x1 - 2 * x2 + rnorm(1)
           )
```

Newey-West adjustment:

```
a.formula <- formula("y ~ x1+x2")
lag <- 1

regco <- a %>% 
   group_by(year) %>%
   group_modify(~tidy(lm(a.formula, data = .x))) %>% 
   select(year,term,estimate) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = term,
               values_from = estimate) %>% 
   ungroup() %>% 
   select(x1, x2, `(Intercept)`) %>% 
   map(
       ~coeftest(
                 lm(.x ~ 1), 
                 vcov = NeweyWest(
                                  lm(.x ~ 1), 
                                  lag = lag, 
                                  prewhite = FALSE
                                 )
                )
      )
```