# "Error in pmg(R ~ LotteryDummy + mkt + smb + hml + Log_mktcap + bm + LaggedR : Insufficient number of time periods"

Tags: r, plm

When attempting to perform a Fama-MacBeth regression analysis on monthly excess stock returns in R with the `pmg()`-function retrieved from the plm-package I am getting the following error message:

```
Error in pmg( : Insufficient number of time periods
```

Below is the command I am trying to run:

```
fpmg <- pmg(R ~ LotteryDummy + mkt + smb + hml + Log_mktcap + bm + LaggedR,
ff.lottery_premiums, index = c("date", "permno"))
```

My dataset is balanced with 1 473 127 observations of American stocks, with variables such as `date`, `permno` (firm identifier), `MthlyExcessReturn`, `MthlyMKT`, `MthlySMB`, `MthlyHML`, `IVOL`, `ISKEW`, `Log_MktCap`, `B/M` and `Lagged6MthlyReturn`, `LotteryPortfolioDummy` and `PortfolioSort` (see enclosed photo [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x158x.png)). I need to run the cross-sectional Fama-MacBeth to get the coefficient of the LotteryDummy over time (representation of lottery premiums)

NOTE! The FamaMacBeth-regressions runs when I only include two independent variables, which have made me suspicious that I may have some "date-permno"-combinations which have too few observations to fully regress the coefficients when I include 3+ independent variables. How do I in that case identify these combinations amongst 1.4mill observations?

I have tried to search the internet for any suggestions, but I can't seem to find any meaningful explanation to what is causing this error message? I have checked for NAs and ensured that there are no duplicate observations of "date-permno".

Comment: Please indicate in the `index` argument the variable specifying the unit of overservation as first place; this is likely `permno` (and not `date`). The variable specifying the time dimension goes into the 2nd place. Also, you might need to convert the `date` variable to something easier, like integers - I do not know if plm can deal with the date specification you have.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Converting the date-variable to "YearMonth" solved my problem, and the regression now runs perfectly fine!

Comment: Take heed to also put fill the `index` argument in the right order or you will have a regression running perfectly fine but with mixed up effects.

Comment: Could I also pick your brain on a related matter? When conducting time- and panel-regressions (with plm for instance) it is common practice to use robust standard errors (HAC-errors by method of Newey-West). However, when using the standard code for computing such errors on the Fama-MacBeth-regression I receive an error-message:

*** cluster_se_fpmg <- coeftest(fpmg, vcov = vcovHC(fpmg_full, cluster ="group", type = "HC1"))[,2] *** 

"Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'R' not found"

What can I do? The similar code runs fine for reguler plm-regressions
Thank you!

Comment: Please do use the search function. Here are some hints: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33324328/newey-west-standard-errors-with-mean-groups-fama-macbeth-estimator

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar code but for my portfolio returns,
I tried the same command

```
plm(excess_returns ~ mkt_excess + hml + smb , data = communications_ff_df , model = "within", index = c("symbol","date"))
```

so see here the index = the grouping variable in your case it is the firmid or permno (CRSP database) which is the id variable. Then other is the time which is the date variable.
my results are

```
Model Formula: excess_returns ~ mkt_excess + hml + smb

Coefficients:
mkt_excess        hml        smb 
   0.90545    0.16240   -0.22671
```

I hope i have answered the issue which you faced. I too had the same issue but i understood what the author meant by flip of the variable